# Can we run a Corda node on an Android mobile device?

Tags: android, mobile, corda

I'm working on creating a CordApp which I'm expecting to run on user's phone. Android as a starting point. From my reading so far, Android phones do not have a JVM running on the phone and the compiled code is converted into either Dalvik or something similar.

Has someone tried to install their CorDapp on an android based mobile device?

I'm a nooby in the area of CordApp as well in android apps but hoping that I can find some good starting tips here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that Corda needs a JVM environment to execute. The most light-weight test we have tried is Raspberry Pi with 2G Memory.

Comment: Peter - thanks for the quick response. In this case, I assume that running a node on mobile devices will not be easily possible since we won't be able to set minimum expected memory on devices. 

Follow up question then - can we spin off a new Corda node automatically based on some user ID and run this node on the server? So if I have a 100 users, would I be able to run 100 different nodes on the same server - one for each user?

Answer (score 1):

(answering the follow-up in the comment above)

You might be able to run several distinct nodes on some server. However at that point there would be little point in using Corda in the first place.

Once you run a node "somewhere else" the user won't own the private key for its node, and all the safety of using Corda disappears. You're reverting to a 'trusted third party' model.